# Mysql INTERVAL sql statement problem

Tags: python, mysql, intervals

I am using the the following sql in MySQL terminal and it works fine.

```
select * from metric_measured_value where metric_id=18 and measurement_time>(now()-INTERVAL 2 year);
```

However, when I used it in python code, it won't work.

```
res = self._db.Query("""SELECT * FROM metric_measured_value
                                            WHERE metric_id = %s
                                            AND measurement_time>(now()-%s)""",
                                            (metric_id, max_interval))
```

Here metric_id=18 and max_interval="INTERVAL 2 year"

The error message is:
Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'INTERVAL 2 year'

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably your DB access library utilizes prepared statements. `INTERVAL` is a MySQL keyword and it is not expected to be passed into prepared statements.

Comment: Thank you. That's the problem. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: What Adam suggests is probably the best way.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of calculating the interval on the database, why not do it in python, and pass it into your measurement time.

```
from datetime import date
max_interval = 2
today = date.today()
interval = date.today()
interval = interval.replace(year=interval.year - max_interval)
delta = today - interval

res = self._db.Query("""SELECT * FROM metric_measured_value
                                            WHERE metric_id = %s
                                            AND measurement_time > %s""",
                                            (metric_id, delta.days))
```

Just saw this question on [gmail style date formating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909134/gmail-style-date-formating-in-python), which suggested [a relative dates](http://jehiah.cz/download/relativeDates.py.txt) module.  It's more relative to now, but it might give some ideas.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's a good idea, but here the interval is not necessarily year, it might be minute, hour, day, month, week or year. Is there a way to easily do this?

Comment: If you know the type, you can write a switch statement.  Then, use datetime.date to calculate difference in days, weeks, months, years, and datetime.datetime to calculate the difference in seconds, minutes and hours.

Comment: Yes, I guess that's the best option I should try. Thanks Adam.